# $AA_1$ it is the bisector of $\angle A_2AA_4$

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ a triangle inscribed în The circle $\Gamma$. The bisector of $\angle BAC$ intersecta $BC$ în $A'$ and $\Gamma$ în $A_1$. Let $AA_2\perp BC, A_2\in BC$ and $A_1A_2\cap \Gamma=\{A_1,A_3\}$, $A_3A'\cap\Gamma=\{A_3,A_4\}$.

IT will be possible that $AA_1$ to be The bisector of $\angle A_2AA_4$?[image]

Comment: So it suffices to show $AA_4$ is the diameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is intended to be a pure geometrical one. The first observation is simple: it is equivalent to show that $AA_4$ is the diameter (you may need to work with some angles to see this!).

This is further equivalent to the fact that $A,A',A_2,A_3$ are on the same circle, so it suffices to show the product $\overline{A_1A_2}\cdot\overline{A_1A_3}=\overline{A_1A'}\cdot\overline{A_1A}$ holds. This suggests to find similar triangles.

By again working with angles, we notice that the triangles $\Delta A_1BA'\sim\Delta A_1AB$ therefore $(\overline{A_1B})^2=\overline{A_1A'}\cdot\overline{A_1A}$.

Similarly, $\Delta A_1BA_2\sim\Delta A_1A_3B$ therefore $(\overline{A_1B})^2=\overline{A_1A_2}\cdot\overline{A_1A_3}$, and the desired result follows.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the figure we have extended $AA_2$ till $A_5$. Because $AA_1$ is bisector one has
$\angle{A'AC}=\angle{A'AB}$ then arcs $BA_1$ and $A_1C$ are equal. It follows that if segment $\overline{A_5A_4}$ is paralell to $\overline{BC}$ then arcs $BA_5$ and $A_4C$ are equal from which $\angle{A_5AA_1}=\angle{A_1AA_4}$ so  **the answer is YES always**.

Calculation gives the equation of the bisector $AA'$
$$\frac{-cx+by}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}=\frac{cx+(a-b)y-ac}{\sqrt{c^2+(a-b)^2}}$$ On the other hand, $c\times \overline{A_2A_5}=b\times(a-b)$ so $\overline{A_2A_5}=\left|\dfrac{b(a-b)}{c}\right|$. Straightforward calculations for the other lines in place gives for the point $A_4$ the same coordinate $y=-\dfrac{b(a-b)}{c}$.

We are done.